# RoR: Providing users with unique email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, architecture

As an RoR newbie, I'm hoping to get insight into what direction I need to take on how to achieve the following (or if its even possible.)

My app will serve as a middle-man between a user and a 3rd party application.  Users of the 3rd party application are provided a unique email address that they can send email(text) to, which is then saved into the 3rd party app.

Instead of users sending text to the 3rd party app, I want intercept this text, and strip out the metadata (date, from, subject, etc.), then save each of the pieces of data accordingly into the 3rd party app.  With that being said, I envisioned providing users with unique email addresses from my application, that I would match up to their 3rd party address.

> Question 1: How would I auto-provision my unique email addresses in
>   RoR? Question 1.1: Are there providers/APIs that allow for this?

The dirty way is for me to use a hosting provider that allows for unlimited email addresses and manually create a lot of them.

I was looking at using a service such as Mailgun or Cloudmailin to help facilitate the capture/parsing of the incoming email contents.

I don't believe a "catch-all" email address would serve me, as users can share my provided email address to anyone, (e.g. via a mailto link on their website), so most people emailing in may not be users in my application.

All advice/assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailgun is your best bet for something like this - you can use a route to match the pattern of your email addresses, POST it to your RoR app, and then handle all of the processing and parsing internally. This will easily let you scale to however many addresses you want (and you can design your addresses so different patterns go different places).

Also, Mailgun/Rackspace "Fanatical Support" is really nice to have when something goes wrong.

Having used MailGun for the last 18 months or so, the one caveat I will give you is that while it is very reliable and easy to use, you will occasionally experience delivery delays depending on how busy they are. These can be a bit confusing or frustrating, but I've never had them "lose" a piece of mail on me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  With Mailgun, do I need to predefine the email addresses, or does it essentially monitor the domain I've pointed to it, and then do as my routes are defined?  In other words, would I need to have user1@myapp.com and user2@myapp.com already configured or in Mailgun can I say if you see an email to user2@myapp.com go here or user1, go there?  Thanks again, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need to pre-configure the email addresses if you are using the Routes feature (which can match a string or a regex). They actually dropped support for POP mailboxes 2 days ago, so you'd either have to use routes or mailing lists. You can match (for example) `user*@myapp.com` (obviously make sure your regex work for your use case), POST it to the appropriate place, and you should be good to go.